# window.onload not called using ajax loadXMLDoc

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I use JavaScript and AJAX's XMLHttpRequest to load content from different *.html in order to advance from my initial top page index.html through other html page.

To add some dynamic behaviour (not yet added) I desire to automatically call a JavaScript function setSelected() via `window.onload=setSelected();` (please see below how I do it precisely).

This works very well when I load from my top page index.html the content of my first html page introduction.html. To check if setSelected() is called I put an alert message and a log-print to the console.

In index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="./js/my_js_lib.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bigbackground" class="clearfix">
    <div id="smallbackground" class="clearfix">
        <iframe src="source/introduction.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In introduction.html:

```
<head>
<link href="../css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/my_js_lib.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload=setSelected();
</script>
</head>

<article id='id_intro' onload="setSelected()">
<div class='clearfix'>
    <button value="Next" onclick="loadXMLDoc('instructions.html',
    'id_intro')" class="button_blue">Next</button>
</div>
</article>
```

In my_js_lib.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url, id)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {   // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {                  
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function setSelected()
{
    alert('I am setSelected');
    console.log('I am setSelected');
}
```

However, utilizing the same syntax at the 2nd loaded html content page instructions.html does not invoke again setSelected() via window.onload.
I do not receive the alert message nor the log print at the console.

In instructions.html:

```
<head>
<script src="../js/my_js_lib.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload=setSelected();
</script>
</head>

<article id='id_instru' onload="setSelected()">
<div class='clearfix'>

<button value="Intro" onclick="loadXMLDoc('introduction.html', 'id_instru')" class="button_blue">Introduction</button>
<button value="Next"  onclick="loadXMLDoc('speakers_inauguration.html', 'id_instru')" class="button_blue">Next</button>
</div>
</article>
```

Moreover, when going back to introduction.html (by clicking on the first button with value="Intro"), again neither the alert message nor the log print at the console appear.

I imagine 2 possible sources of error:

a) The `window.onload=setSelected();` is only set once at the html header when the initial top page index.html gets loaded, but it may not be added to the html  section when I load further content via AJAX, right?

b) The onload event handler of the HTML5 element  doesn't get triggered when I load it the way I do via AJAX.

Best,

Comment: if you see javascript debug in your browser,you can find error `setSelected() is not defined`, iframe not allowed to call parent page registered script.

Comment: sorry, I debug already using the JavaScript Console. The function setSelected() is defined. Loading the whole document (via pressing the return key to load the url) triggers a call to it via window.onload. However, loading either introduction.html or instructions.html via pressing the corresponding button to trigger its loading via the AJAX call does not call setSelected().

Comment: i suggest you to use `jquery` and `live` method,this is hard in native `javascript`.

Comment: I solved the problem by exchanging the <button> element with a hyper reference <a href="*.html" ... and kept the rest as it is. It's not the exact way I wanted to have this, but window.onload get's called cause the hyper reference really loads the stuff such that the event handlers are invoked. Thanks for trying to help out ...